# Enable/Disable tabs using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

I have been able to enable and disable tabs in HTML and Javascript. I want that the color of tab  previous to the current tab should be different and disabled and the color of tabs next to current tabs should be disable and of different color

Ex:-
Step1 **Step2** Step3 Step4

Suppose Step2 tab is selected I want the color of Step1 should be Green and it should be disabled
and the color of Step3 and Step4 should be Blue and should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JQuery plugin rather than using pure javascript. please refer these links for some tab navigation plugins.you can download and easily configure.

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/11-useful-jquery-tab-navigation-solutions
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I have used jqueryUI. The thing is that the css for disabled is same for all but I want that the color for previous should be different and the color for next should be different

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
    http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/

Or This:
    http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/cc324/